# Is my lisp evaluation correct?

Tags: lisp

I know my answer is dead wrong, I would like to know how I would be able to reach the answer.  What did I do wrong?

```
X = (setf X '(88 ((11 21 31 41)) (90 91 92 93)))
```

I have to write LISP expression which evaluates to the list:

```
(11 (11 21 31 41) (88 90 91 92 93))
```

My Answer:

```
(list (caadr X) (cdddr X))
```

Answer (score 1):

These should get you going:

```
CL-USER> (cadr X)
((11 21 31 41))
CL-USER> (caadr X)
(11 21 31 41)
CL-USER> (caaadr X)
11
CL-USER> (cons (caaadr X) (cadr X))
(11 (11 21 31 41))
CL-USER> (caddr X)
(90 91 92 93)
CL-USER> (car X)
88
CL-USER> (cons (car X) (caddr X))
(88 90 91 92 93)
```

(Experimenting in the REPL is a very effective way of finding things out.)

Comment: Ah ok.  May you please link me a site that has REPL online for LISP?

Comment: @obsolutemal https://jscl-project.github.io/, but you can easily download a lisp and start doing it offline (sbcl and ccl work in both linux and windows)

Comment: would it be possible to use list instead of cons?  I'm having trouble figuring out when to use what.

Comment: @obsolutemal `(cons a b)` is the pair of `a` and `b`. `(list a b)` is a list with `a` and `b`– it is `(cons a (cons b nil))`. (There's some good free material on Lisp available online, for instance [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).)